# How to watch time without activity and interact with asp.net page

Tags: .net, session, timeout, tracking

Let's say we have 30 mins session timeout.

What is the best way to track user and interact with the page when there is 1 minute till sessions timeouts.

I have found this JQuery solution: [link](http://paulirish.com/demo/idle-timer?comment=textarea+has+been+idle+for+3+seconds%0D%0A)

But I am not sure it is exactly what I need. This will reset if user moves with mouse. I need to track activity such as requesting another page or refreshing page.

Something like godaddy.com has if you are inactive for longer periods, if you dont react they will automatically logout you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to keep the session alive is to have a really simple timer on the page that's started on page load. You don't need jQuery for the timer, but it's handy for refreshing the session:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get("/keepalive.ashx");
}, 29 * 60 * 1000); // time in milliseconds
```

If you'd rather end the session, just change it into a redirect:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    location.href = "/logout.aspx";
}, 29 * 60 * 1000);
```

As timers don't survive over page loads, it won't log the user out if they're still active. If you have some other things on the page that you would like to reset the timeout, it's probably the best to make a function out of it:

```
var sessionTimer;

function resetSessionTimeout() {
    if (sessionTimer)
        clearTimeout(sessionTimer);
    var sessionTimer = setTimeout(...);
}
```

And call that whenever you want the session timeout to be reset.

Comment: I dont want to keep session, I want to close after inactivity for security reason. But I will use this for future as well. Thanks

Comment: Actually I think that I will combine both solutions, it seems that I could add session time if someone actually edits text as he is active. Would be really bad idea to just count down and logout him because he has not saved work for 30 minutes but is actually active with writing

Answer (score 0):

Try [Session Time Out Tricks](http://www.msjoe.com/2010/02/session-time-out-tricks/) by Joe Stagner